# Winsock MSG_DONTWAIT equivalent

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

While porting unix C++ code under windows and using sockets/winsock API, I am confronted with this on the **server** side:

```
recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, MSG_DONTWAIT); // UNIX code
```

I found from [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/578140-send-with-msg_dontwait-and-setrlimit-in-windows/) that the equivalent of the MSG_DONTWAIT flag with WSA is to set the socket in nonblocking mode with `ioctlsocket`: call FIONBIO with arg != 0 ([here is the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Being on the server side, I have though two sockets:

- The socket for connecting to server:

  ```
  SOCKET ListenSocket = socket(...)
  bind(ListenSocket, ...)
  listen(ListenSocket, ...)
  ...
  ```
- The temporary socket for accepting connections from clients:

  ```
  SOCKET ClientSocket;
  ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, ...)
  recv(ClientSocket, ...)
  ...
  ```

Which socket do I call `ioctlsocket` with? And where? (I mean where wrt [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014955/socket-connect-vs-bind)?)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If so it would be really helpful to post an answer!

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636286/can-a-socket-be-made-non-blocking-only-for-the-recv-function ...

Answer (score 1):

The ListenSocket is as the name implies the socket listening on incoming (TCP/IP) connections and serves only that purpose. You
call accept() later on that socket. accept() returns another socket, 
as soon as there is an incoming connection. This is the ClientSocket
which will be used to send/recv data to/from. It is also the socket
that needs to be put into non-blocking mode in order to emulate
the behaviour of MSG_DONTWAIT (which is specific to Linux, don't
know right now if POSIX defined this also).

So, put short, call ioctlsocket after accept and before recv on the
ClientSocket.

Note: If you call accept() again you can also have more than one connection, each with a seperate socket returned by accept(). You
then would use something like select() to multiplex I/O.