# AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'MSG_DONTWAIT'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am trying to use the flag '`MSG_DONTWAIT`' in the following python code:

```
RECV_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
buff = memoryview(bytearray(RECV_BUFFER_SIZE))
x = client_socket.recv_into(buff, RECV_BUFFER_SIZE, socket.MSG_DONTWAIT)
```

where I am just reading from the socket.

Strangely, when I use 'MSG_WAITALL' flag, the code works fine, however it fails with the following error:

```
x = client_socket.recv_into(buff, RECV_BUFFER_SIZE, socket.MSG_DONTWAIT)
```

> AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'MSG_DONTWAIT'

when I try to use `'MSG_DONTWAIT'` from the same class **MsgFlag** in which `'MSG_WAITALL'` was present. I am running this on windows platform.

Comment: Might be platform specific, are you on Windows by chance?

Comment: yup, running this on windows!

Comment: Might be a version issue of `fluent` . https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-python/issues/129

Comment: how do I update this on my system? I remember I just installed the latest version of python on my system 2 days back!

Comment: As @bgse assumed, it is platform specific. WinSock does not implement that constant, hence it is not available in Python's socket package on a Windows installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You receive the error because `MSG_DONTWAIT` is not defined in the Python socket module for Windows. Python only acts is as a tiny wrapper around the low level socket system, and it is Winsock2 on Windows. And specifically `MSG_DONTWAIT` seems to not be defined by Posix and does not exist in Winsock. On a Unix or BSD system, it would be defined in the Python `socket` module, I have just controlled on a FreeBSD 10 system.

According to [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29010214/3545273), and after reading the related [post](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/578140-send-with-msg_dontwait-and-setrlimit-in-windows/), I think that you have to explicitely put the socket in non blocking mode on Windows:

```
RECV_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
buff = memoryview(bytearray(RECV_BUFFER_SIZE))
client_socket.setblocking(0)                   # put socket in non blocking mode
try:                                           # a BlockingIOError is raised if nothing is available
    x = client_socket.recv_into(buff, RECV_BUFFER_SIZE, 0)
except BlockingIOError:
    x = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the setblocking() function, I am now using a combination of client_socket.setblocking(True) and  client_socket.settimeout(3) to wait for 3 seconds until we receive anything from the sever!